# Modifications Mime In Upload Photos

Tags: php

I have php code to upload photos. On the types of photographs can be mentioned using the code `$check["mime"]` and the result is like this: `The file image/png has been uploaded.`
I want to turn it into **The file .png has been uploaded.**
What could this be?

If it is difficult, perhaps there are other ways besides using MIME?

Here are the codes:

```
<?php
$target_dir = image/";
$imglo = $check["mime"];
$target_file = $target_dir . $imglo;
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". $imglo . " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `$target_dir = image/";` that's an outright syntax error and is throwing off syntax highlighting - it should read as `$target_dir = "image/";` . If that's your real code, then may be the root of the problem. and if not, then it's a permissions issue and/or file size exceeds allowed on server.

Comment: Make a dictionary `mime-type => caption` and select a proper one.

Answer (score 0):

Create some dictionary, e.g.

```
$mime_captions = array(
    'image/png' => '.png', 
    'image/jpg' => '.jpg',
    // other mimes
);
```

After that, knowing mime-type you can get proper caption:

```
echo $mime_captions['image/png'];
```

And code can be changed to:

```
echo "The file ". $mime_captions[$imglo] . " has been uploaded.";
```

Or if your mimes always start with `image/` substring - use `str_replace`:

```
echo "The file ". str_replace('image/', '.', $imglo) . " has been uploaded.";
```

Comment: Do you think I can read thoughts? What have you done and what is not working?